# DataRowView returns null while handling SelectedCellsChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

I've been trying to handle the *SelectedCellsChanged* event of a WPF DataGrid control to be able to fill some fields from the DataGrid on one of its rows' selection event.
it has worked well in a previous project when i was using Ado.net and binding data to the grid as DataTable.
but when i started to use Linq and bind data as a var or a list there a problem has been appeared.

this is my code to fill the grid:

> ```
> private void fill_data_grid()
>    {
>        var items = from it in dc.items
>                    orderby it.date_added descending
>                    select it;
>        dg_items.ItemsSource = items;
>    }
> ```

this is the *XAMl* code of the DataGrid that i want to handle its cell selection event

```
<DataGrid  Margin="374,133,10,61" x:Name="dg_items"     
SelectedCellsChanged="dg_items_SelectedCellsChanged" 
Loaded="dg_items_Loaded">                    
</DataGrid>
```

this is the event handler:

> ```
> private void dg_items_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
>    {
>        try
>        {
>            DataRowView _DataView = this.dg_items.CurrentCell.Item as DataRowView;
>            //Problem Happens up here ***************************************
>            if (_DataView != null)
>            {
>                txt_code.Text = _DataView.Row["code"].ToString();
>                txt_name_ar.Text = _DataView.Row["name_ar"].ToString();
>                txt_name_en.Text = _DataView.Row["name"].ToString();
>                txt_international_code.Text = _DataView.Row["icode"].ToString();
>                txt_supplier_name.Text = _DataView.Row["supplier"].ToString();
>                cb_supplierType.Text = _DataView.Row["supplier_type"].ToString();
>                cb_producer_comp.Text = _DataView.Row["producer_company"].ToString();
>                cb_producer_comp.Text = _DataView.Row["medical_group"].ToString();
>                cb_material.Text = _DataView.Row["material"].ToString();
>                txt_restrictions.Text = _DataView.Row["restrictions"].ToString();
>                txt_side_effects.Text = _DataView.Row["side_effects"].ToString();
>                cb_bigUnit.Text = _DataView.Row["bigger_unit"].ToString();
>                cb_smallUnit.Text = _DataView.Row["small_unit"].ToString();
>                cb_medical_shape.Text = _DataView.Row["pharma_type"].ToString();
>                dp_production_date.Text = _DataView.Row["date_produced"].ToString();
>                dp_expire_date.Text = _DataView.Row["date_expire"].ToString();
>                txt_amount_of_unit.Text = _DataView.Row["amount_in_unit"].ToString();
>                cb_item_type.Text = _DataView.Row["cat"].ToString();
>                txt_notes.Text = _DataView.Row["notes"].ToString();
>                txt_price_per_unit.Text = _DataView.Row["price"].ToString();
>                txt_reduction_main.Text = _DataView.Row["main_reduction"].ToString();
>                txt_reduction_extra.Text =_DataView.Row["extra_reduction"].ToString();
>                txt_tax.Text = _DataView.Row["tax"].ToString();
>                txt_amount_of_units.Text = _DataView.Row["amount"].ToString();
>              txt_limit_of_reordering.Text=_DataView.Row["limit_of_order"].ToString();
>                txt_quick_access.Text = _DataView.Row["quick_access_code"].ToString();
>            }
>        }
>        catch (Exception ex)
>        {
>            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
>        }
>    }
> ```

The problem happens while taking an instance of the current cell item as a *DataRowView*

> DataRowView _DataView = this.dg_items.CurrentCell.Item as DataRowView;

the DataView is null although the CurrentCell.Item has values inside its columns.

I've tried the same code using ADO.Net and it worked..

the following code is my previous ADO.Net code

> ```
> private void FillDataGrid()
>    {
>        UserDAO doa = new UserDAO();
>        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = doa.GetEmps().DefaultView;
>    }
> ```

Where GetEmp() returns a DataTable.

so i don't know why it gives null when selecting a DataGrid's row. can anyone know why ?

Thanks